# Magento 2.3 sort categories alphabetically

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, category-tree, category-listing

I want to sort the categories in a Magento 2.3.1 install in alphabetical order (on the frontend!). I'm aware of the fact that you can sort it by dragging it in the Magento admin panel. But since the store I'm working on has more than 3000 categories, that's not an option. The categories also update from time to time, so it has to be a "future proof" solution.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? The only things I can find are for M1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your module **di.xml** (app\code\vender\module\etc\di.xml) place this line

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Category"/>
```

Create the file Vendor\Module\Model\Category.php and place this code in it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Catalog category model
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace elastron\elcustom\Model;

/**
 * Resource model for category entity
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category
{

    /**
     * Return child categories
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function getChildrenCategories($category)
    {
        $collection = $category->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
            'url_key'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'all_children'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'is_anchor'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'is_active',
            1
        )->addIdFilter(
            $category->getChildren()
        )->setOrder(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
        )->joinUrlRewrite();

        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

let me know if you need any assistance !

Don't forget to run upgrade, compile an clean/flush cache

Comment: before applying a preference on a model, you might want to verify this function is not called anywhere else? I'd say using preference on a resource model is likely very intrusive / meaning likely to override the class behaviour in more places than you intend to..

Comment: Yes but I'm only overriding this specific method. I understand you're concern but this is not a "dangerous" method.

Comment: to be fair, the advantage of your solution is that is will do what the question asks. In terms of best practice, it is not ideal, but it is quite practical to offer, thanks for challenging

Comment: I'm not taking it personally ;) I surely don't know everything, I'm still learning and I'm only working with Magento since January :): I would appreciate if you could guide me towards some documentation that supports your opinion.What would be the safest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Upvoted yours.. no solution is perfect, only relevant to your context. Simplicity sometimes outperforms perfection. Great attitude you have

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions to this problem, Joao71's solution is simple to write and should do the trick.

In terms of best practice, **preference** are to be used if **plugin** is not possible.
The reason is because if 2 modules do use the same **preference**, only one in the system will be eventually be used (we call this a conflict) and that is what **plugin** resolves.

**plugin** will allow you to take over any public function and yet, any further **plugin** on the same function will not be compromised. In your case, **getChildrenCategories** is a public function and that is therefore working

Finally, the solution I would offer in this instance would be to write a `script / command-line` that reorders the categories. This way solves the problem to do it manually but more importantly does not touch an inch on the integrity of the Magento system

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, never thaught from the perspective of code maintenance *maybe because I don-t have many preferences on my module :)) . Up voted !